# how to use Group By in subquery

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

```
select FirstName, LastName

from Customer AS A, Sale AS E

where A.CustomerID=E.CustomerID

AND group by sum(Total)
```

I keep coming up with an error, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Your query makes no sense

Comment: I'd start with the manual, and/or some kind of tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting the `sum(total)` to appear in your outputted record set, it needs to be up in the `SELECT` portion of your query. Furthermore, your syntax is backwards. We put the fields that we want to group by in the `GROUP BY`, fields being aggregated using a function like `sum`, `max`, `avg`, etc go up in the `SELECT`. Lastly, the `GROUP BY` clause stands on it's own, the `AND` after your `WHERE` clause is not needed.

I believe you are wanting something like:

```
select FirstName, LastName, sum(total) as total_sum

from Customer AS A, Sale AS E

where A.CustomerID=E.CustomerID

GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```